# initializing class A (with a reference member) within class B

Tags: c++, qt, class, oop

i'm trying to make a simple currency converter and I have some problems with my class designed to make the calculations.
I want to create an object of this class in my MainWindow to use the total variable for displaying the result in a widget on my appi form.

Member functions aren't all here yet, but the problem I have is that i get a 
'Calculator' : no appropriate default constructor available error in mainwindow.cpp

While I do know what that means, I don't know how to avoid (solve) the issue because i kind of need the reference on the map to get the echange rates needed.

.cpp

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <ui_mainwindow.h>

class Calculator
{
public:
    explicit Calculator(QMap<QString,double> &currency_map);
    void multiply(double x, double y);
    void getValues(QString strFrom, QString strTo);

private:
    double total, firstCurr, secondCurr;
    QMap<QString,double> &map;
};
```

.h

```
#include "calculator.h"

Calculator::Calculator(QMap<QString,double> &currency_map):map(currency_map)
{
    total = 0;
    firstCurr = 0;
    secondCurr= 0;
}

void Calculator::getValues(QString strFrom, QString strTo)
{
      QMapIterator<QString, double> i(map);
    while(i.hasNext())
        {
            if(i.key() == strFrom)
                firstCurr=i.value();
            if(i.key() == strTo)
                secondCurr = i.value();
    }
}

void Calculator::multiply(double x, double y)
{
    total = x * y;
}
```

and now im trying to create an object of that class in my MainWindow class:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <ui_mainwindow.h>
#include "calculator.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QMap<QString,double> &currency_map, QWidget *parent = 0);

    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    parser currency_parser;
    Calculator calc; // error

};
```

MainWindow.h

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QMap<QString, double> &currency_map, QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->from_Combox->addItems(currency_parser.currency_list);
    ui->to_Combox->addItems(currency_parser.currency_list);
}
```

the idea behind was that i have a Map in my main in which i save all my data needed and pass the map around to classes that use it.

i'll post my main even tho im not sure if it's needed

```
#include "downloader.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "parser.h"
#include "calculator.h"
#include <QApplication>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QMap<QString,double> currency_map;

    downloader d;
    d.Do_download();

    parser p;
    p.read_line(currency_map);

    MainWindow w(currency_map);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
};
```

Comment: You must use the `MainWindow` constructors member initializer list to instantiate the `calc` member and pass `currency_map` as parameter.

Comment: i can't do that because i have to have the QMap<QString,double> &map;
initialized before the constructor afaik

Comment: What do you mean? It is initialized before. I said you need to use the member initializer list (same thing you did for `map` in the `Calculator` constructor).

Comment: Oh, that's right, i missread your comment. thanks alot mate!

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs, because you don't specify the appropriate constructor for class `Calculator` in the `MainWindow` constructors member initializer list (the compiler want's to use the default constructor then):

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QMap<QString, double> &currency_map, QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
, ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
, calc(currency_map) // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
{
    // ...
}
```